# finding the same words in two strings in c

Tags: c, string, compare, words

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    char* firstString = argv[1];
    char* secondString = argv[2];
    int i, j;
    int flag = 0;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(firstString); i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<strlen(secondString); j++)
        {
            if (firstString[i] == secondString[j])
            {
                flag = 1;   
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf ("true\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("false\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

So the program I need to write is to compare 2 text strings, and if the same words in the second string appears in the first string, then i print true, otherwise, I print false.

So for example,
"I hate you" "hate" --- this would print true
"I hate you" "I am a walrus" --- this would print false

But for some reason, this code just keeps print false and I dunno what's wrong with it.  Would anyone be able to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a debugger or paper and pencil and go through your logic. Your code does not match the task you described.

Comment: Loops with `for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)` are bad; they convert a linear algorithm into a quadratic one.  Calculate the length of the string just once.

Comment: You can use `strstr` from `string.h`.

Comment: To compare **words** you will need to **tokenize** the string so that you are actually comparing **words** instead of **characters**. You have a couple of options. `strtok` is what you want unless you want to roll-your-own. To accomplish your comparison, you need only tokenize **one** of the strings. You can then use `strstr` (as Cool Guy notes) to compare whether the tokens (words) appear in the second string. It's a fairly straight-forward task. If you use `strtok` **note** the first call takes the `pointer` as the first argument, all remaining calls take `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try as :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* firstString = argv[1];
    char* secondString = argv[2];
    int flag = 0;
    int count=0;

    int len2=strlen(secondString);
   while(*firstString!=NULL)
   {
      while((*firstString==*secondString)&&(*secondString!='\0')){
          firstString++;
          secondString++;                             
          count++;                            
      }
    firstString++;
    if(count==len2){
     flag=1;
     break;
    }
    else
     flag=0;

 }   


    if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf ("true\n");

    }
    else
    {
        printf ("false\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually checks if all the characters in the first string are found in the second string.  Since you want to match whole words separated by spaces, please look into the strtok function on how to break the strings into substrings first.  Then you can use strcmp to compare each of the words.

Answer (score 0):

The inner **for loop** should stop at a match between two characters not at mismatch, so the only error in your code is the position of the **break** statement in the below lines:

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(firstString); i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<strlen(secondString); j++)
    {
        if (firstString[i] == secondString[j])
        {
            flag = 1;   
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Place **break** statement at the position shown in below code. The extra **if statement** at the end of outer **for loop** checks whether the current character matched or not and **breaks** at mismatch i.e. flag=0:

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(firstString); i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<strlen(secondString); j++)
    {
        if (firstString[i] == secondString[j])
        {
            flag = 1;   
            break;     //break position changed
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)   //extra conditional check
       break;
}
```